# How to Identify when Taskbar setting "Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode" is set to On

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

I have a custom Form and a custom control, and I am facing a problem with the control size when I turn on the setting "*Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode*" to true. How can I get the value whether this property is enabled or whether the TaskBar has been hidden or visible?

I have checked with the option **FormBorderStyle** which always returns **Sizable**. Can you please suggest a way?

```
if (this.FormBorderStyle == FormBorderStyle.None)
{
  c.SetBounds(0, 0, topWidth, height);
}

else if (this.CompositionEnabled && (c as StatusExt != null && (c as StatusExt).IsFormManager)
{
  if (borderValueChanged)
   {
      c.SetBounds(StatusForm.BORDER_WIDTHNORMAL, topHeight + StatusForm.BORDER_WIDTH, displayWidth, height);
   }
  else
   {
      c.SetBounds(StatusForm.BORDER_WIDTH + borderWidth, topHeight + StatusForm.BORDER_WIDTH - borderWidth, topWidth - borders.Left - borders.Right, height);
   }
 }
```

This is the code I have and I am setting x and y to 0 when the FormBorderStyle is set to None and I need to set same x and y when the mentioned property to true.

Comment: Can you explain the problem, instead of just say you face a problem?  Also, please post some code to show how you're trying to deal with it.

Comment: See the `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea`. Or `Rectangle rect = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea`, if you have more than one display (if `Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1`).

Comment: @Archer I have a Custom status bar control which is docked to top and i have given some padding to it when the TaskBar is visible and the padding will be 0 when FormBorderStyle is None ( FormBorderStyle to None will provide full form with TaskBar hidden ). But when i turn on mentioned property to true,the taskbar will be hidden, but i dont have any condition to check for it for setting padding to 0.

Comment: Sorry, but without code you won't get an answer.  Please supply a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Do you have your Taskbar also docked to the top as well?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway No it is docked to bottom only.

Comment: @Archer Sorry for not providing code, i am really new to asking questions in the site. Now i have attached my code